# using intellij-markdown in kotlin android project

Tags: android, kotlin

I wanted to use intellij-markdown in one android kotlin project - but it does not survive the java roundtrip. Now I am searching for the least painful way to deal with this problem and hence ask here - perhaps someone faced the same problem. All solutions I have in mind currently are not really nice as they all diverge from upstream.

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
Error:1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:transformClassesWithDexForProdWithFirebaseDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pre-dex '/home/ligi/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/markdown/0.1.23/f02dce4ef95be9f24a6ea59de2c187f597befb70/markdown-0.1.23.jar' to '/home/ligi/git/SurvivalManual/android/build/intermediates/transforms/dex/prodWithFirebase/debug/folders/1000/10/markdown-0.1.23_4afcc7019db1f3375984c600cc493df386228117'
```

Comment: How exactly did you compile intellij-markdown? The default build.gradle of intellij-markdown generates Java 6 bytecode and will not trigger this error.

Comment: I do not compile it - I use the one via maven repo from maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/markdown' }